# Счетчик кликов на экране

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты

Я делаю автокликер в PyQt5, и я хочу сделать так, чтобы на кликере был мини счетчик `cps`, который будет считывать клики в секунду по экрану.

Мне нужно чтобы `cps` показывалось в лайбеле `Numb`.

Мой код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(171, 122)
        Form.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(171, 122))
        Form.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(171, 122))
        Form.setStyleSheet("")
        Form.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.Clicker = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.Clicker.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 171, 121))
        self.Clicker.setText("")
        self.Clicker.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Python-projects/Clicker/Interface/2.jpg"))
        self.Clicker.setScaledContents(True)
        self.Clicker.setObjectName("Clicker")
        self.Status = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.Status.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 61, 61))
        self.Status.setText("")
        self.Status.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Python-projects/Clicker/Interface/4.jpg"))
        self.Status.setObjectName("Status")
        self.Numb = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.Numb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 20, 81, 101))
        self.Numb.setStyleSheet("color:#f00;\n"
"font: 87 45pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.Numb.setScaledContents(True)
        self.Numb.setObjectName("Numb")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.Numb.setText(_translate("Form", "01"))
        
        
class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.old_pos = None
        
    # вызывается при нажатии кнопки мыши
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):         
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = event.pos()

    # вызывается при отпускании кнопки мыши
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = None

    # вызывается всякий раз, когда мышь перемещается
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not self.old_pos:
            return
        delta = event.pos() - self.old_pos
        self.move(self.pos() + delta)        
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWidget()
    w.show()
#    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
#    ui = Ui_Form()
#    ui.setupUi(Form)
#    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: Сюда должно писать cps]

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста лучше по какому виджету вы хотите кликать, чтобы изменять значение счетчика или по какому событию это должно происходить. Что означает: "будет считывать клики в секунду по экрану".

Comment: После запуска программы счетчик cps сразу должен работать и он будет считывать клики мышки. Тоесть сколько кликов в секунду было сделано

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt, QTimer


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(171, 122)
        Form.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(512, 512))
        Form.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(512, 512))
        Form.setStyleSheet("")
        Form.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.Clicker = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.Clicker.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 512, 512))
        self.Clicker.setText("")
        self.Clicker.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("lena.jpg"))
        self.Clicker.setScaledContents(True)
        self.Clicker.setObjectName("Clicker")
        self.Status = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.Status.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 61, 61))
        self.Status.setText("")
        self.Status.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Ok.png").scaled(61, 61))
        self.Status.setObjectName("Status")
        self.Numb = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.Numb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 20, 181, 101))
        self.Numb.setStyleSheet("color:#f00;\n"
"font: 87 45pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.Numb.setScaledContents(True)
        self.Numb.setObjectName("Numb")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.Numb.setText(_translate("Form", "0"))
        
        
class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.old_pos = None
        self._click = 0                                     # +++ 
        
        self.timer = QTimer()                               # +++ 
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)   # Миллисекунды       # +++ 
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.onClicked)          # +++ 
        self.timer.start()                                  # +++ 

    def onClicked(self):                                    # +++ 
        self.Numb.setText(f"{self._click}")                 # +++     
        self._click = 0                                     # +++ 
    
        
    # вызывается при нажатии кнопки мыши
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):         
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = event.pos()
            
            self._click += 1                                # +++ 

    # вызывается при отпускании кнопки мыши
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = None

    # вызывается всякий раз, когда мышь перемещается
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not self.old_pos:
            return
        delta = event.pos() - self.old_pos
        self.move(self.pos() + delta)        
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

> Оно считывает клики, если я кликаю в области окна программы, а мне нужно так чтобы оно считывало клики и за пределами окна программы

Вам в помощь:

```
from pynput import mouse       # pip install pynput
```

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt, QTimer
from pynput import mouse                                       # pip install pynput


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(171, 122)
        Form.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(512, 512))
        Form.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(512, 512))
        Form.setStyleSheet("")                          # vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv  # +++  
        Form.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

        self.Clicker = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.Clicker.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 512, 512))
        self.Clicker.setText("")
        self.Clicker.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("lena.jpg"))
        self.Clicker.setScaledContents(True)
        self.Clicker.setObjectName("Clicker")
        self.Status = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.Status.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 61, 61))
        self.Status.setText("")
        self.Status.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Ok.png").scaled(61, 61))
        self.Status.setObjectName("Status")
        self.Numb = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.Numb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 20, 181, 101))
        self.Numb.setStyleSheet("color:#f00;\n"
"font: 87 45pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.Numb.setScaledContents(True)
        self.Numb.setObjectName("Numb")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.Numb.setText(_translate("Form", "0"))


class ButtonReleaseManager(QtCore.QObject):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=self._handle_click)
        self._listener.start()

    def _handle_click(self, x, y, button, pressed):
        if pressed:
            self.clicked.emit(x, y)
        
        
class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.old_pos = None
        self._click = 0                                     # +++ 
        self._all_click = 0                                 # +++ 
        
        self.timer = QTimer()                               # +++ 
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)   # Миллисекунды       # +++ 
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.onClicked)          # +++ 
        self.timer.start()                                  # +++ 
        
        self.manager = ButtonReleaseManager()               # +++ 
        self.manager.clicked.connect(self.allClicked)       # +++
        
    def allClicked(self):                                   # +++ 
        self._all_click  += 1                               # +++ 

    def onClicked(self):                                    # +++ 
        click_not_window = self._all_click - self._click    # +++
#        self.Numb.setText(f"{self._click}")                   
        self.Numb.setText(f"{click_not_window}")            # +++       
        self._click = 0                                     # +++ 
        self._all_click = 0                                 # +++
        
    # вызывается при нажатии кнопки мыши
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):         
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = event.pos()
            
            self._click += 1                                # +++ 

    # вызывается при отпускании кнопки мыши
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = None

    # вызывается всякий раз, когда мышь перемещается
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not self.old_pos:
            return
        delta = event.pos() - self.old_pos
        self.move(self.pos() + delta)        
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Оно считывает клики, если я кликаю в области окна программы, а мне нужно так чтобы оно считывало клики и за пределами окна программы

Comment: @MDofer я добавил ответ для вас.

Comment: Спасибо, вы меня прям выручяете сегодня